# Two dimensional arrays of type actors

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and I am trying to implement a system of multiple actors of same type. I am using Akka Actors for the same. I want to keep these actors in a two dimensional array but i am not able to initialize the 2d array. Below is the actor initialization.

```
var fighter1 : ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[Fighter],name = "fighter1")

//2d array of type Actor(Fighter)
var LocationMatrix= Array.ofDim[Fighter](3,3)

//initialization
LocationMatrix(0)(1)=fighter1  //this throws error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fighter1` is of type `ActorRef` and `LocationMatrix` holds `Fighter` objects therefore you cannot put `fighter1` inside it.

Try with this:

```
var locationMatrix = Array.ofDim[ActorRef](3,3)
```